# why in the console of hook/commit in tortoise we can see only errors?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, hook, post-commit, post-commit-hook

I created a post-commit hook which inform the user of some others information.
I put in my code:

```
REPOS="$1"
REV="$2"
TXN_NAME="$3"
SVNSYNC='/opt/collabnet/csvn/bin/svnsync';
echo "my message" >&0;
echo "Your commit has been performed successfully." 1>&2;
exit 1;
```

Could you please told me why for these messages we can display it only if I put `"exit 1"`?

Is there any other way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Subversion server is designed such that the only user-visible messages that are sent back are error conditions (anything written to `STDERR`, usually).

A successful commit *is* communicated back to the client, and the client can then display a nicer message if the developer choses to do so.

Any non-error messages that need to be communicated to the client from the server need to be done via other means; email, RSS feed, a bot talking to IM or an IRC channel, etc.

Comment: Thank you alroc, so finally  is not possible to communicate it in the console

Comment: Correct. Anything you send back to the client via hook will make the client think the commit failed.